# If $\{X_n\}$ is a positive sequence with $L \gt 1$, show that $X$ is not bounded and hence is not convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> $\lim(x_{n+1}/x_n) = L \gt 1$. Show that $X$ is not a bounded sequence and hence is not convergent.

Suppose the sequence $X = x(n)$ is bounded. Then there exists a $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x_n| \leq M ~~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider the set $$S := \{\textrm{all upper bounds of X}\}$$
$S$ is bounded below by $M$. By the completeness property, define $M := \inf(S)$. Define $L'$ such that $1 < L' < L$. Since $L' > 1$, then $M/L' < x_n \leq M ~~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $M < L' \cdot x_n$.

By the definition of limits, there exists a $K$ such that $n \geq K ~~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus $x_{n+1}/x_n > L'~~ \forall n \geq K$ and $x_{n+1} > L' \cdot x_n$.

Combining the two inequalities together, we see that $$M < L' \cdot x_n < x_{n+1}$$
However this contradicts the fact that $|x_n| \leq M~~\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $M$ was defined as the greatest lower bound of the set $S$.

---

- I am not sure if I can simply define $M : = \inf(S)$ and that I am reaching the right contradiction that M was assumed to be the $\inf$ or if I am supposed to contradict that M was simply a lower bound of $S$.
- I also feel like my proof doesn't quite flow together as well as it should and was wondering how coherent my thoughts looked to other people.

Comment: What is $L$? It would better if you restated the claim in the body of the post more clearly. Also you are choosing $L'$, you are not defining it.

Comment: I updated the post with the problem for more clarity. I chose $L'$ to be a positive real number between 1 and the limit of the sequence $L$

Comment: My edit was for a typo $x_{x+1}$ for $x_{n+1}$ in the 1st line.

Comment: More simply take $n_0$ such that $n\ge n_0\implies x_{n+1}/x_n>P=(L+1)/2.$ Then $x_{n_0}\ne 0$ and $P>1.$ Now for $m\ge 1$ we have $|x_{m+n_0}|=|x_{n_0}\prod_{j=0}^{m-1}(x_{n_0+j+1}/x_{n_0+j})|>|x_{n_0}|\cdot P^m\to \infty$ as $m\to \infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=L>1$, we can choose a positive integer $N$ such that $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}>\frac{1+L}2>1$ for $n\geqslant N$. Let $M>0$ and choose a positive integer $N'$ such that $N'>\frac{2M}{1+L}$. Then for $n\geqslant N+N'$ we have
$$
\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \geqslant \frac{x_{N+N'+1}}{x_{N+N'}} = \prod_{n=N}^{N+N'}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} \geqslant N'\left(\frac{1+L}2\right) > M,
$$
so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty$.

Comment: what is that notation after the first equals sign?

Comment: $\prod$ ? The same as $\sum$, except for products instead of sums.